# Laravel race condition

Tags: php, laravel, redis

I have a race condition in my Laravel project where multiple requests may be trying to access and modify the same cache key at the same time. Correct condition is that the first request will obtain the lock and proceed to execute its critical section of code, while the second request will wait until the lock is released by the first request. I use following code:

```
$lock = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache::lock('sell-25');
$lock->get(function () use ($lock) {
    \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache::put('sell-25', ['t' => '544554']);
    $lock->release();
});
dump(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache::get('sell-25', ['empty']));
```

when use lock, I can't put new value to cached value. In other words, How can i lock cache for requests except current request?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/cache#atomic-locks   The get method also accepts a closure. After the closure is executed, Laravel will automatically release the lock: